# How can I say "even today" or "even now"?

Tags: phrase-requests

I would like to say "even today" or "even now".

I want to talk about Japanese culture and customs. Would it be something like:

> 今日まで日本の中でたくさんしゅうかんで、文化があります。

I want it so say something like "even now or even today there are many customs and cultures in Japan." but I am having trouble saying it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「今でも」 is what you're looking for.

> 今でも日本には習慣と文化がたくさんあります。

今(now) + でも(even)

Though if I were you I might say 残っています instead of あります.